# Conditional tag for wordpress archive first page only

Tags: wordpress, tags, conditional-statements, categories, archive

I’m trying to place a widget only on the first page of a category archive using Widget Logic with Wordpress. I am able to place the widget in the category archive using is_archive(‘category1’) but this places it on all the archive pages, I just want my widget to appear of the first archive page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a conditional for first page of archive:

```
if ( !is_paged() ) :
       the_archive_description( '<div class="archive-description">', '</div>' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) you can access, 'paged', which is not set if there is only one page or contains the number of the current page

I cannot test this right now, but I assume it should work:

```
 //Get the current page number, default is 1
 $current_page = get_query_var('paged', 1);

 if ($current_page == 1){
     //Your code
 }
```

Comment: Hi Fernando! Thanks for your suggestion. I actually figured a way of doing this using a combination of conditional tags. I used the pair of conditions is_category('cat') with !is_paged() when I realised that the first page of an archive is not considered 'paged' by WP, but all the pages after it are.

Comment: This worked better for me: `$current_page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`